# libapache2-mod-security installation on docker

Tags: linux, docker, google-app-engine

I have docker custom image with apache install . I have to install the libapache2-mod-security on docker conatiner i am using the below command inside the docker container but getting error.

**apt-get install libapache2-mod-security**

root@8e8d98a4910e:/opt/drupal# apt-get install libapache2-mod-security
Reading package lists
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-security
root@8e8d98a4910e:/opt/drupal#

Answer (score 0):

Depends from the source container, but there is tendency for all mainstream distributions to remove the cache objects before releasing containers to make them smaller. The Aptitude (`apt`) needs the cache to know which repository has the package.

Before you can install things in the container you will need to rebuild the cache by calling

```
apt update
```